# Cordova path assets instead of android_assets

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I got this in my folders :
[image]

But on my android device, i have a file not found error because it looks for andoid_assets instead...
[image]

Where can i set my folder path ?

Comment: Are you working with Android Studio?

Comment: nope, only the sdk and my own mobile device

Answer (score 0):

fixed,
do not put underscores as prefix for folder name..

Answer (score 0):

Need to access the asset files from your main root(projectname->www) only on android device need to set the path like **file:///android_asset/www/yourfilepath**

E.g., file:///android_asset/www/images/xyz.png